# Remove double quote within double quote

Tags: sed

Currently im processing data that have behaviour like this

```
"Halo A","Test B","Yes, This is test","No Problem, we can test, right","{Okay}","Test oneTest two","One,Two,Three",",","Done","","Test (1,2,3)","Yes","",
"1", ""Test 1. Try, 2.Again, and 3. Done"",",
```

The expectation data can have like this,

```
"Halo A","Test B","Yes, This is test","No Problem, we can test, right","{Okay}","Test oneTest two","One,Two,Three","","","Done","","Test (1,2,3)","Yes","",
"1","Test 1. Try, 2.Again, and 3. Done","",
```

Im trying using sed below

```
s/\(|"[^"|]*\)"\([^"|]*"\)/\1\2/g
```

But the sed seems not working after it meet ( ) and .

```
"Halo A","Test B","Yes, This is test","No Problem, we can test, right","{Okay}","Test oneTest two","One,Two,Three","","","Done","","Test (1,2,3)",""Yes"","",
"1",""Test 1. Try, 2.Again, and 3. Done"","",
```

Comment: Why do you replace the first `"` with a `'`?

Comment: Sorry, typo.. already fix with " thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match nested quotes, you need to target the match e.g nested quotes.

```
sed -E 's/"("[A-Za-z0-9., ]*")"/\1/g' input_file
```

As you can see, the command targets only quotes within quotes and extracts only the nested quote while excluding the main quote.

```
$ sed -E 's/"("[A-Za-z0-9., ]*")"/\1/g' input_file
"Halo A","Test B","Yes, This is test","No Problem, we can test, right","{Okay}","Test oneTest two","One,Two,Three","","","Done","","Test (1,2,3)","Yes","",
```

Comment: Hi @HatLess thank for your sharing solution. It's work for the text that i shared. however, in the file that i have, there is a line that having "1", ""Test 1. Try, 2.Again, and 3. Done"","", and if the column having dot . it will not removing the double quote.

Not sure why its not working with some special character.

Im trying adding \W as per my understanding the -E means adding regex, but still not replace double quote that have dot

Comment: Hi @HatLess, i try to test with edited the result still the same.
Just curious, do we need to define special character one by one? is there any keyword that cover special character?

Comment: Hi @HatLess, this is the command that im running
 sed -E 's/"("[A-Za-z0-9.,]*")"/\1/g' sample_test_2.txt
"Halo A","Test B","Yes, This is test","No Problem, we can test, right","{Okay}","Test oneTest two","One,Two,Three",",","Done","","Test (1,2,3)","Yes","",
"1",""Test 1. Try, 2.Again, and 3. Done",",

For reference
 cat sample_test_2.txt
"Halo A","Test B","Yes, This is test","No Problem, we can test, right","{Okay}","Test oneTest two","One,Two,Three","","","Done","","Test (1,2,3)",""Yes"","",
"1",""Test 1. Try, 2.Again, and 3. Done"","",

Comment: Thanks, i can parse it now.